# How to overwrite CustomProperties in SoapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have defined a Custom Property on Test Case level in `SoapUI`. I have tried to change the property name in a teststep (to change an endpoint url), but it does not work.

My initial definition in Custom Properties:

- Name  = param
- Value = somevalue

In TestStep  "Properties" I have tried:
 - Name = param
 - Value = othervalue

or

- Name = ${#TestCase#param}
- Value = othervalue

But it has no effect. The value of my property is still "somevalue"

It would be great if someone could help me to solve this.

Comment: What type of test step are you using to overwrite? A groovy script test step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Groovy Script` test step to overwrite, then use below code snippet to do the same.

```
//show the existing value
log.info "Existing property value is: ${context.testCase.getPropertyValue('param')}"

//set new value
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('param', 'otherValue')
```

Comment: I tried the "Properties" test step. It works with the 'Groovy Script' test step, thank you